# Pass hidden field value using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-post, query-string

I have a normal `hidden` `Input field` where I am generating `random` `string`. I need that to be appended to the URL where I am trying to post data to another page.

I have done this and works pretty well.

**`url:'Upload.html?field1=newvalue',`**

This is my hidden input field

```
<input type="hidden" id="randomdirectory"/>
```

Now instead of `newvalue` in the `query string` I need to pass my `random directory value`.

Comment: Is this an AJAX request or a page refresh form submission?

Comment: Sorry guys for the late response as I am trying to get it work with all of your suggestion but unfortunately none of them worked and its an ajax request.

Comment: +1 for all those who tried to help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

easily accomplished 
just do the following

```
var value = $("#randomdirectory").val();
url:'Upload.html?field1='+value ,
```

thats it ..

Comment: @rainkeys-Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

Just give a name to the hidden field.

```
<input name="field1" type="hidden" id="randomdirectory" value="randomvalue"/>
```

Comment: I know it's kind of hard to pick up from the fact that it's not stated in the question, but I believe he's making an ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this is a parameter to an ajax call (as others already have), a slightly better practice is this:

```
url: 'Upload.html',
data: { field1: $('#randomdirectory').val() }
```

This will ensure that your query string is URL encoded properly (jQuery handles it for you).

Answer (score 1):

```
url: 'Upload.html?field1='+$("#randomdirectory").val()
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right and the ID is randomly generated then you need something of this type:

```
url: 'Upload.html?field1=newvalue&field2=' + $('[type="hidden"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

**page1.html**

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnid" value="0">

<script>
    var id =$("#hdnid").val();
    window.location.href="pathofpage2.htmlpage" +"#"+id;
</script>
```

**page2.html**

```
<script>
    var id =window.location.hash.substring(1);
</script>
```