# Retrieve hidden field value from ajax in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit

I dont understand, in PHP,  how to retrieve a simple hidden field value submitted from ajax. 
I looked other questions but were related to more complicated situations and I did not understood.

```
   <form id="form" action="" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="hi">
   </form>




$('#form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
            alert('sent');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: `$('#selector').val()`

Comment: You don't even have to make an ID for it @Daan, You can also search by name which is needed for forms. `$('[name=tcol1]').val()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data will be sent as a `POST` Request to your php url.

You can retrieve the Key Values Pairs from your form in php with the `$_POST` variable.
The key to your hidden field is the `name` attribute of the input field.

```
<?php
    echo $_POST["foo"];
?>
```

How to send Form Values: [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144837/pass-hidden-field-value-using-jquery)

About: [PHP POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Answer (score 1):

Since, its a post request **$_POST['foo']** will give you the value of hidden element in php script